# Google-Play-Services: Creating custom waiting room UI

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am about to implement a real-time-multiplayer for my android application with the google play games
services and got some problems to listen to room updates. Iam not that experienced,
so please forgive the possible understanding problems.

My intention is that I need to get informed, if anybody has joined my recently 
created room or created another room himself with the same variant as my room.

I have tried to listen on the RoomStatusUpdateListener, but after I created a room,
this listener never get called and I wonder why. What does get called, is the 
RoomUpdateListener, but it contains not the callback methods which I need.

I know that it is recommended to use the android build in 
waiting room ui and to use Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent() to 
start an activityForResult, but I need to create something like my own waiting room
and do not know how. Apparently the google activity (the waiting) room does get 
informed about changes, so there must be a way to observe these.

As far as I can tell, Iam trying to do something like:

1. creating multiple rooms with different variants
2. listen on any room for updates (a player joins or created the same room)
3. join the room with the update from step 2.

Does anybody have an idea how I can achieve that?
I would be so glad. Sorry for my bad english.

Greetings ,
Steve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since nobody was able to answer my question or whatever, I think it is valid to
provide my result of investigation as an answer myself.

I was able to find the important method calls, which are needed for a custom UI implementation.
They are basically located in the two interfaces `RoomUpdateListener` and `RoomStatusUpdateListener` and need to be provided to the `RoomConfig.Builder`.

The lifecycle of a game is like the following:

**Step 1**

- create the room via

`Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());`

**Step 2**

- `RoomUpdateListener: onRoomCreated` The client attempts to create a real-time room.

**Step 3**

- `RoomStatusUpdateListener: onPeerJoined` Called when one or more peer participants join a room.
- `RoomStatusUpdateListener: onRoomConnecting` One or more participants have joined the room and have started the process of establishing peer connections
- `RoomStatusUpdateListener: onP2PConnected` Client is successfully connected to a peer participant.
- `RoomStatusUpdateListener: onConnectedToRoom` The client is connected to the connected set in a room.
- `RoomStatusUpdateListener: onPeersConnected` Called when one or more peer participants join a room.

**Step 4**

- `RoomUpdateListener: onRoomConnected` All the participants in a real-time room are fully connected.

That's it. Now the participants are connected and can send messages via `Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage` and the other send methods.

Comment: Can you answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739109/google-play-games-realtime-multiplayer-getting-participant-id-and-storing-it-to#)?